# XSLT transform error

Tags: xslt

I have the following xml:

```
<RootNode xmlns="http://someurl/path/path/path">
    <Child1>
        <GrandChild1>Value</GrandChild1>
        <!-- Lots more elements in here-->
    </Child1>
</RootNode>
```

I have the following xslt:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns="http://someurl/path/path/path" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <NewRootNode xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <NewChild1>
                <xsl:for-each select="RootNode/Child1">
                    <NewNodeNameHere>
                        <xsl:value-of select="GrandChild1"/>
                    </NewNodeNameHere>
                <!-- lots of value-of tags in here -->
                </xsl:for-each>
            </NewChild1>
        </NewRootNode >
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**The problem:** this is the my result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<NewRootNode xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <NewChild1 />
</NewRootNode>
```

I am expecting to see:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<NewRootNode xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <NewChild1>
        <NewNodeNameHere>Value</NewNodeNameHere>
        <!-- Other new elements with values from the xml file -->
    </NewChild1>
</NewRootNode>
```

I am missing of the information inside of NewChild1 that should be there.

I think my for-each select is correct, so the only thing I can think of is that there is a problem with the namespace in the Xml and the namespace in the xslt. Can anybody see what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stylesheet namespace should be `http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform` instead of `http://someurl/path/path/path`.

Also, since the input XML uses a namespace all your XPath expressions should be namespace-qualified:

```
<xsl:template match="/" xmlns:ns1="http://someurl/path/path/path">
   <NewRootNode xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <NewChild1>
         <xsl:for-each select="ns1:RootNode/ns1:Child1">
            <NewNodeNameHere>
               <xsl:value-of select="ns1:GrandChild1"/>
            </NewNodeNameHere>
            <!-- lots of value-of tags in here -->
         </xsl:for-each>
      </NewChild1>
   </NewRootNode>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is caused by the namespaces.

Since the xml defines `xmlns="http://someurl/path/path/path"`, it is not in the default namespace anymore.

You can define that namespace with an name like `xmlns:ns="http://someurl/path/path/path"` in the xsl, and then use that name in the XPath expression.

The following works for me:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:ns="http://someurl/path/path/path" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
    <NewRootNode xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <NewChild1>
            <xsl:for-each select="ns:RootNode/ns:Child1">
                <NewNodeNameHere>
                    <xsl:value-of select="ns:GrandChild1"/>
                </NewNodeNameHere>
            <!-- lots of value-of tags in here -->
            </xsl:for-each>
        </NewChild1>
    </NewRootNode >
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```